# не получается задать передвижение второму кругу

Tags: javascript, canvas

не получается задать передвижение второму кругу

```js
    var Point = function (x, y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            return this;
        }
        var Circle = function (point, radius) {
            this.point = point;
            this.radius = radius;
            this.isInside = function (pt) {
                return Math.pow(pt.x - point.x, 2) + Math.pow(pt.y - point.y, 2) < Math.pow(radius, 2); 
            };
            return this;
        }
     
        var element;
        var circle = new Circle(new Point(15, 15), 10);
        var circle2 = new Circle(new Point(25, 25), 10);
        var deltaCenter = null
     
        var drawCollection = [circle, circle2];
        function Draw(){
            var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            drawCollection.forEach(function(item){
                drawCircle(item);
            });
        }
        
        window.onload = function() {
            Draw();
            element = document.getElementById('canvas');
            element.addEventListener('mousedown', startDragging, false);
            element.addEventListener('mousemove', drag, false);
            element.addEventListener('mouseup', stopDragging, false);
            element.addEventListener('mouseout', stopDragging, false);
        }
        
        function startDragging(e) {
            var p = new Point(mouseX(e), mouseY(e));
            if(circle.isInside(p)) {
                deltaCenter = new Point(p.x - circle.point.x, p.y - circle.point.y);
            }
        }
        
        function drag(e) {
            if(deltaCenter != null) {
                circle.point.x = (mouseX(e) - deltaCenter.x);
                circle.point.y = (mouseY(e) - deltaCenter.y);   
                Draw();
            }
        }
        cnt=0
        function stopDragging(e) {
            deltaCenter = null;
        }
        
        function mouseX(e) {
            return e.clientX - element.offsetLeft;
        }
        
        function mouseY(e) {
            return e.clientY - element.offsetTop;
        }
        
        function drawCircle(circle) {
            var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.fillStyle = "red";
            ctx.arc(circle.point.x, circle.point.y, circle.radius, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.fillStyle = "green";
            ctx.arc(circle2.point.x, circle2.point.y, circle2.radius, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
            ctx.fill();
        }
```

```html
    <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: сделайте ваш код запускаемым чтобы была возможность лучше понять проблему

Comment: Я Вам ответил в другом вопросе, но к сожалению его кто-то удалил или что-то еще случилось. Поскольку мне лень переписывать одно и то же, то причина в том, что вы задаете им обоим одно и то же значение.

Comment: не пойму, на какой строке задаётся одно и тоже значение

Comment: В вашей прошлой попытке на jsfiddle вот в этом: `(mouseX(e) - deltaCenter.x)` и этом `(mouseY(e) - deltaCenter.y)`.

Comment: чем этот вопрос отличается от [этого](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/543394/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0#543406)?

Comment: @AlexKrass, его автор удалил